# Registering all models in an app with admin programmatically including all fields in list_display

Tags: django, django-admin

I am able to register all models in an app with the admin programmatically as such:

```
app = apps.get_app_config('school')

for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

Now, I would like to do further configuration to show the models with list display (grid) and include all fields available. For example:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'school_id', 'position_id', 'school_contact', 'phone', 'extension',)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

And I want to do this for each and every model in my app. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
app = apps.get_app_config('school')

for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    model_admin = type(model_name + "Admin", (admin.ModelAdmin, ), {'list_display': tuple([field.name for field in model._meta.fields])})
    admin.site.register(model, model_admin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies as i haven't checked this. But i think `get_all_field_names()` method should be able to get this.

I think you might be able to use it in this way: `[field.name for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]`. But this is deprecated from django 1.8. Might work for now but it will be discontinued in future.

Sorry couldn't comment on your question due to insufficient reputation.